# CSocket does not work on LAN

Tags: c++, networking, mfc, network-programming, winsock2

I'm learning network-programming and try to develop a simple socket application that used CSocket class from MFC. And found myself hitting a wall that need some help.

I want the server side listens on a certain port, example `1001`. Then from other computer, on the same sub-net, it should successfully telnet to that port. My program works correctly on localhost, but fail on the LAN, although I have opened that port on firewall of listener. 

Here is my code from listener:

```
//CListenSocket is derived from CSocket
CListenSocket myListener;
myListener.Create(1001);    
myListener.Listen();

//OnAccept()
  //CConnectSocket is also derived from CSocket
CConnectSocket myConnect;
myListener.Accept(myConnect);
```

I built the release version using VS2008, here is the screenshot of the configuration properties:
[image: my program build's configuration]
So at this stage, when I run the program, `netstat -an` show this line:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:1001           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Then on that machine `telnet 127.0.0.1 1001`, this line appears.

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:1001         127.0.0.1:2681         ESTABLISHED
```

So I think my code is correct. After that I tried from other machine with the same sub-net, and the telnet fail:

```
Connecting To 192.168.2.199...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1001: Connect failed
```

Note: that my listener is on `192.168.2.199`, and the connector is on `192.168.2.3`. Both nodes can successfully ping and sharing file with each other. I also add both `Inbound Rule` and `Outbound Rule` for the program on my firewall, here is the properties of the rule:
[image: My rule for the program]

For more information: On my listener node, there is Apache HTTP server installed on it, so I have the other node telnet to port 80, and it works...

So where did I miss? please help, thank you in advance.

**EDITION 1:**
**Attempt for troubleshooting**
So after hitting my head to the table for a while, I quickly make a decision for not use telnet for client anymore. But make a small client program to catch errors:

```
//CClientSocket is derived from CSocket
CClientSocket clientSocket;
clientSocket.Create();
int iConnect = clientSocket.Connect(ipAddress,1001) //ipAddress is a variable of MFC's text box on GUI.

switch (iConnect)
{
case 0:
    {
        DWORD errorNumber = ::GetLastError();   //catch error code
        CString s_errorNumber;                
        s_errorNumber.Format("%d",errorNumber); //format to CString for easy echo
        MessageBox("Connection fail :"+s_errorNumber)
        clientSocket.ShutDown(CAsyncSocket::both);
        clientSocket.Close();
        break;
case SOCKET_ERROR:
    if (::GetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) 
        clientSocket.ShutDown(CAsyncSocket::both);
    else
        clientSocket.AsyncSelect();
    break;
default:
    {
        MessageBox("Connection Established.");
    }
    break;  
}
```

And the error number is: `10061`. I checked this code on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) an it is `WSAECONNREFUSED`-Connection refused.

Now we know the problem here must be somewhere in the listener's firewall... still hiting my head to the table.